# Как обойтись без дублирования кода(Elif) и реализовать посредством функций?

Tags: python, функции, рефакторинг

Как обойтись без дублирования кода(Elif) и реализовать по средством функций?

```
import random

n = 'Not Again!'

while True:
    user = input("Enter a choice (rock, paper, scissors, lizard, spoke):\n>>> ")
    possible_actions = ["rock", "paper", "scissors" , "lizard" , "spoke"]
    answers = ["y" , "n"]
    computer = random.choice(possible_actions)
    if user not in possible_actions:
        print(f'Invalid input "{user}"')
        continue
    print(f"\nYou chose: {user}\nComputer chose: {computer}\n")
    if user == computer:
        print(f"Both players selected {user} . Draw!")
    elif user == "rock":
        if computer == "scissors":
            print("You win!")
        else:
            print("You lose.")
    elif user == "paper":
        if computer == "rock":
            print("You win!")
        else:
            print("You lose.")
    elif user == "scissors":
        if computer == "paper":
            print("You win!")
        else:
            print("You lose.")
    elif user == "lizard":
        if computer == "scissors":
            print("You lose.")
        else:
            print("You win!")
    elif user == "spoke":
        if computer == "stone":
            print("You win!")
        else:
            print("You lose")

    while True:
        play_again = input("Play again? (y/n):\n>>>")
        if play_again == "y":
            break
        if play_again not in answers:
            print(f'Invalid input "{play_again}"')
            continue
        if play_again == "n":
            print(f'Invalid input "{n}"')
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как задать правило в Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1496733/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%b2-python)

Answer (score 1):

В первую очередь на ум приходит задание таблицы результатов:

```
user = input("Enter a choice (rock, paper, scissors, lizard, spoke):\n>>> ")
possible_actions = ["rock", "paper", "scissors" , "lizard" , "spoke"]
results =         [[  0,      -1,        1,           1,        -1  ],     #rock 
                   [  1,       0,       -1,          -1,         1  ],     #paper
                   [ -1,       1,        0,           1,        -1  ],     #scissors
                   [ -1,       1,       -1,           0,         1  ],     #lizard
                   [  1,      -1,        1,          -1,         0  ]]     #spoke
answers = ["y" , "n"]
computer = random.choice(possible_actions)
if user not in possible_actions:
    print(f'Invalid input "{user}"')
    continue
print(f"\nYou chose: {user}\nComputer chose: {computer}\n")

index_user = possible_actions.index(user)
index_computer = possible_actions.index(computer)

result = results[index_user][index_computer]

if (result < 0):
    print('You lose')
elif (result > 0):
    print('You win!')
else:
    print('Draw')
    continue
```

Comment: зачем в конце каждой строки `;`?

Comment: @Danis, нервный тик. Неужели мешается?

Comment: нет, просто очень странно выглядит